# Breeze.js: Returning empty set when requested database does not exist

Tags: breeze

Currently we are using Breeze.js and Angular to develop our applications.  Due to some persistent legacy issues, we have two databases ('Kenya' and 'Rwanda') that cannot be merged at this time, but have the same schema and metadata.  Most of the time, the client knows which database to hit and passes the request through the .withParameters() function or the .saveOptions() function.  Sometimes we want to request the same query from both databases (for example, if we are requesting a list of all available countries), and we use a EntityManager wrapper on the client to manage this and request the same query from each database.  This is implemented through a custom EFContextProvider which uses the data returned to determine the appropriate database and creates the appropriate context in CreateContext().

To further complicate things, in some instances one or the other database won't exist (these are local deployments created through filtered replication), but the client won't know this.  Therefore, when querying for a list of all countries, it issues two requests and one will cause failures because the context cannot be instantiated properly.

This is easy enough to detect on the Server.  What I would like to do is to detect whether the requested context is available and, if not, return a 200 response and an empty set.

I can detect this in the Breeze DBContextProvider CreateContext() method, but cannot figure out how to cause the request to fallback gracefully to a empty-set response.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I was looking for, but it probably makes more sense since most of the work is being done on the client-side:

Instead of trying to change the controller, I added a getAvailableDatabases to the C# controller actions and use that to determine which of the databases I will query from the client.